# How to skip the second part of (JavaScript if statement) if the first part is false

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have this code:

```
  if (window.content.document.getElementById("error-msg") != null )
  {
    if (window.content.document.getElementById("error-msg").offsetParent !== null) 
    {
...
    }
  }
```

Can it be written in one if statement?

I tried the following...

```
if ( (window.content.document.getElementById("error-msg") != null) || (window.content.document.getElementById("error-msg").offsetParent !== null) ) {}
```

But, it didn't work, and produces an error:

> TypeError: window.content.document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: You need `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: If only we had the [existential operator](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:existential_operator)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The common idiom is to use the `&&` operator like this

```
var errorMsg = window.content.document.getElementById("error-msg");

if (errorMsg && errorMsg.offsetParent) {
    ...
}
```

Here, JavaScript will evaluate `errorMsg` first and if it is [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), then it will evaluate the `errorMsg.offsetParent` part. The condition will be satisfied only if both the expressions in `&&` are Truthy.

**Note:** The Truthy evaluation will return `false`, if the expression being tested is `0`, `false` etc (See the list of Falsy values [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)). So, if you want to test if they are not `null`, just write that explicitly, like this

```
if (errorMsg !== null && errorMsg.offsetParent !== null) {
    ...
}
```

---

On the other hand, the `||` operator will evaluate the second operator only if the first expression is Falsy. In your case, if

```
(window.content.document.getElementById("error-msg") != null)
```

is `true`, it means that `getElementById("error-msg")` returns `null`. Since the first expression is evaluated to be Truthy, it evaluates the other expression and it effectively tries to check

```
null.offsetParent !== null
```

That is why it fails.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want to use &&

```
if (a != null && b != null) {
    // Do something.
}
```